# Unity crashes on Launch

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have installed latest version of unity(5.6.0f3) from https://store.unity.com. Every time i try to launch the unity I get unity bug reporter window popped up.I am not able to create a new project or use unity. I uninstalled latest version and installed unity 5.3.5f1 version. But still I am facing the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the 64bit or the 32bit version of unity?

Comment: @Hristo I installed 64 bit

Comment: And what operating system do you have? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @Hristo I am using 64 bit WIndows 10 OS

Comment: Did you try to launch it as an administrator?

Comment: Look in the C:\Users\<<your username>>\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\editor.log and tell us what you see

Comment: I assume you've tried to uninstall and reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe memory problem in your pc, try to end task of anything running even google chrome (because it takes a lot of memory) and then run Unity as administrator. 
It can be also that your windows is 32 bits and you wanna run Unity3d 64 bits.

I hope this helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the problem like this.
In my case this bug reporter appeared when I tried to open the "unity-3d-simplefps-master" project downloaded from GitHub.
So I renamed the source folder name and I just avoided this bug reporter.
Best wishes!